# CSS Grid - Align elements of unknown height vertically inside items

Tags: css, css-grid

Some time ago I asked this question about equal height elements within flexbox items: [Flexbox - Align elements of unknown height vertically inside items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071516/flexbox-align-elements-of-unknown-height-vertically-inside-items). And it turned out that it's impossible with Flexbox.

Can this be achieved with **CSS Grid** layout?

Comment: you either rethink the layout. either try using javascript for equal height of all elements

Comment: Can you post a code sample in your question? We need to see your HTML structure especially. A more detailed explanation and Illustrations would also improve the quality of this question and make it more useful.